# How to correctly publish CakePHP 3 to external server?

Tags: php, cakephp, hosting

I'm writing application in Cakephp-3. I have got local server (Xampp) and external (Apache).

In my local server, all redirect works fine, but when I upload my Cakephp project into external server, I have got error while invoking links.

> Error: The view for OnasController::index() was not found.

[image]
**such a view, of course, exist there**!!

I think that's the fault of an external server configuration: path, webroot etc.

I will be very grateful for any solution that help solve my problem.

This is my screen where is project localization.

**Ok sorry !! Edited !!!**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your screen is missing the most important part, the structure inside of the `MyEso` folder, specifically the path to the view template file.

Comment: I can't see the "Template/Onas" folder in your above screenshost.  Show me the actual file that's being complained about? Also I can't see whether the screenshots above is hanging off of /home/bloodq or not.

Comment: I edited post. As you see folders and files exist. I think that i should configure access file or .. ?

Comment: Just take a closer look at the filename,  compare it to the one in the error message, and keep in mind that unlike Windows filesystems, *nix systems are usually case-sensitive by default.

Comment: thx, its work. Case-sensitive was a issue..